# Authenticating with the REST web API of MS Dynamics CRM 2016 online

Tags: python, rest, azure-active-directory, adal, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm trying to access the new REST API for building a server-to-server interface to integrate the CRM with other applications such as the web-shop etc.

I have tried both ways of getting an access-token from Azure AD:

Client credentials

```
import adal

token_response = adal.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    'https://login.microsoftonline.com/abcdefgh-1234-5678-a1b1-morerandomstuff', 
    client_id,
    secret
)
```

and user/password

```
import adal

token_response = adal.acquire_token_with_username_password(
    'https://login.microsoftonline.com/abcdefgh-1234-5678-a1b1-morerandomstuff',
    'interface@crm.my_domain.com',
    'my_password'
)
```

In both cases, token_response gets a token-object, containing accessToken, refreshToken, expiresIn and so on. So I don't think there's an error up to this point.

Then I try to make a simple request to the web API:

```
headers = {'Authorization': '%s %s' % (token_response.get('tokenType'),
                                       token_response.get('accessToken'))}

r = requests.get('https://domain.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/Product',
                 headers=headers)
```

This always returns a HTTP 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied.

```
('WWW-Authenticate', 'Bearer error=invalid_token,
error_description=Error during token validation!,
authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/eabcdefgh-1234-5678-a1b1-morerandomstuff/oauth2/authorize,
resource_id=https://domain.api.crm4.dynamics.com/')
```

The user that tries to make the request has Office-365-Administrator privileges and in the CRM has all manager roles and the administrator role. Which for my taste is even a bit much, but I read somewhere, that the user has to have office-365 admin privileges.
In the Azure AD there is an Application configured which has "delegated rights" to the CRM ("Access CRM Online as organization users").

What am I missing here? Or is my REST-get-request wrong?
Microsoft documentation for the new API is practically nonexistent - whenever you click some link you get docs for the older APIs (organization API etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`acquire_token_with_username_password` has an [optional parameter](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/2be94fd6266141d26a6b3be58eca1e530e39c020/adal/__init__.py#L79) for specifying which resource you want access to:

> resource (str, optional): The resource you are accessing.  Defaults to
>   'https://management.core.windows.net/'.

You should thus be able to specify that you want access to CRM by adding resource as an argument to `acquire_token_with_username_password`:

```
token_response = adal.acquire_token_with_username_password(
    'https://login.microsoftonline.com/abcdefgh-1234-5678-a1b1-morerandomstuff',
    'interface@crm.my_domain.com',
    'my_password',
    resource='https://domain.crm4.dynamics.com'
)
```

This should give you a proper token for accessing CRM.

After getting the correct token, you also need to modify your Web API call slightly (from `Product` to `products`):

```
r = requests.get('https://domain.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/products',
                 headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've also found some sample code to get people started: http://jlattimer.blogspot.de/2015/11/crm-web-api-using-python.html

Comment: For Ruby instead of Python, have a look at this Pull Request: https://github.com/visoft/ruby_odata/pull/59 and use the Microsoft libraries where possible

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ruby